# How to arrange data on Partitions Physical Storage

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, storage

I want to move data on the partition to the start of the partition physically. The files are scattered on the whole partition, free spaces are in between. I want that all data should be on one side and free space on one side.

Here is the explanation of the data on the partition. White dots free space and others are data.

[Storage Distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4xiV.png)

[SMART Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5M8c.png)

Comment: Why does it matter? What are you trying to achieve? You are not going to get any significant speed boost by doing so.

Comment: Have you considered that doing so would quickly lead to increased file fragmentation due to them having no space to grow?

Comment: @Mokubai My system is very slow...   and I have experienced a boost by doing this...   But I did this by making a new Partition and installing OS...
My system was taking about 15 minutes to boot but after installing on the new partition it was taking less than 2 minutes. Now after a month, the system is again becoming slow due to that. Therefore I want some tool that re-arranges data. My disk random read-write speed is about 1.2 Mbps.

Comment: If you know any tool which can do this tell me...

Comment: Such big differences in speed are not normal. I suggest to check the SMART data of your disk, and also to run `chkdsk`.

Comment: Added SMART result

Answer (score 0):

The program that you used to show the use of space on your drive will exactly do that, what you are asking for in your question.

Apart from that you already have two reallocated sectors. Your seek error rate seems to be high but I can't explain that.

It's time to replace this drive as the number of reallocated sectors tends to grow typically. Depending on your use profile you might consider replacing the HDD by a SSD.
Do not defragment SSDs.